# Creating a calendar control using CSS: How to auto layout events

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I'm creating a JavaScript based calendar control, which when showing a single day needs to list any events occuring. I'd like the use the CSS `float:left` in order to get the browser to automatically layout the events.

I'd like for the events to automatically stack, so that they float to the far left when possible. Then stack as if there is overlap with another event.

**However I'm having problems, it currently looks like this:**

[image]

**This is the result I want to achieve:**

[image]

How can I achieve this effect using `float`?

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS, it may be something obvious but we won't be able to tell without it! :)

Comment: Are you floating an entire column, or just the boxes? Also, how are you setting their vertical position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `"clear:both;"` css style attribute to your block with the green element?

Also, you may find that an already created jQuery plugin like [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) could serve your needs.

Comment: This might be it the problem, but it's difficult to say with no code, Nice plugin BTW!

Comment: @Camilo-Diaz I've decided just to use FullCalendar. It's really everything I was aiming for (i.e. replication of Google calendar functionality). Thanks for bringing it to my attention.